# Any way to resolve dependencies sooner?

Tags: c#, autofac

When resolving a service, there's a difference between using an auto-generated factory and not. For example, if I have these classes:

```
public class A {
    public delegate A Factory();
    public A(B someDependency) {}
}

public class B {
    public B(String s) {}
}

public class AFactory {
    private readonly Func<B> _b;

    public AFactory(Func<B> b) {
        _b = b;
    }

    public A Create() {
        return new A(_b());
    }
}
```

And register them thusly:

```
var cb = new ContainerBuilder();
cb.RegisterType<A>();
cb.RegisterType<AFactory>();
var c = cb.Build();
```

Calling `c.Resolve<AFactory>()` will immediately result in a `DependencyResolutionException`. Calling `c.Resolve<A.Factory>()` will return a delegate that will throw the `DependencyResolutionException` when it is invoked.

It seems to me that the behavior provided by `c.Resolve<AFactory>()` is more desirable since the exception will be thrown when resolving a service, not at some point in the future when the service is actually used. I'm looking for a general solution that can be applied to all registrations in my project.

Is there some way to alter the behavior of `c.Resolve<A.Factory>()` in my example to make it throw the exception immediately?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> It seems to me that the behavior provided by c.Resolve() is more desirable since the exception will be thrown when resolving a service

Resolving a delegate will result in a lazy operation. It means that the concrete resolve operation may be made time after the initial resolution. Between the moment of the initial resolve and the final resolve the container may change.

Look at the following example :

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        ContainerBuilder builder = new ContainerBuilder();
        builder.RegisterType<Foo>().AsSelf();
        builder.RegisterType<Bar1>().As<IBar>();

        IContainer container = builder.Build();
        Foo foo = container.Resolve<Foo>();

        foo.Do(); // ==> DependencyResolutionExtension 

        // update the container with the Pouet type
        builder = new ContainerBuilder();
        builder.RegisterType<Pouet>().AsSelf();
        builder.Update(container);

        foo.Do(); // OK


        // update the container with another IBar
        builder = new ContainerBuilder();
        builder.RegisterType<Bar2>().As<IBar>();
        builder.Update(container);

        foo.Do(); // OK 
    }
}

public class Foo
{
    public Foo(Func<IBar> barFactory)
    {
        this._barFactory = barFactory;
    }

    private readonly Func<IBar> _barFactory;

    public void Do()
    {
        IBar bar = this._barFactory();
    }
}
public interface IBar { }
public class Bar1 : IBar
{
    public Bar1(Pouet p) { }
}
public class Bar2 : IBar
{
}
public class Pouet { }
```

if you really want an exception thrown at the initial resolve operation I can see 2 solutions :

1. create a `RegistrationSource` that provide a new implementation for `Func<T>` (or the delegate you want). Not too difficult but you will have to resolve the type during initial resolve operation.

The code below is a sample on how to do that. I didn't test it with different lifetime registration type and I don't know how disposal of these objects will works for some case. This code should works for simple case

```
    /* 
     * This code was not fully tested and it is not optimized
     * It doesn't fully managed the lifetimescope of the object and memory leak may appear
     */
    internal class FixedFactoryRegistrationSource : IRegistrationSource
    {
        internal class FixedFactory<T>
        {
            public FixedFactory(T instance)
            {
                this._instance = instance;
            }

            private readonly T _instance;

            public T GetInstance()
            {
                return this._instance;
            }
        }

        public FixedFactoryRegistrationSource(ContainerBuilder builder)
        {
            builder.RegisterGeneric(typeof(FixedFactory<>)).As(typeof(FixedFactory<>));
        }

        public Boolean IsAdapterForIndividualComponents
        {
            get { return true; }
        }

        public IEnumerable<IComponentRegistration> RegistrationsFor(Service service,
                                                                    Func<Service, IEnumerable<IComponentRegistration>> registrationAccessor)
        {
            IServiceWithType serviceWithType = service as IServiceWithType;
            if (serviceWithType == null || !serviceWithType.ServiceType.IsGenericType)
            {
                yield break;
            }
            if (serviceWithType.ServiceType.GetGenericTypeDefinition() != typeof(Func<>))
            {
                yield break;
            }

            Type elementType = serviceWithType.ServiceType.GetGenericArguments()[0];
            Type fixedFactoryType = typeof(FixedFactory<>).MakeGenericType(elementType);
            Service fixedFactoryService = serviceWithType.ChangeType(fixedFactoryType);

            MethodInfo getInstanceMethod = typeof(FixedFactory<>).MakeGenericType(elementType).GetMethod("GetInstance");
            foreach (IComponentRegistration registration in registrationAccessor(fixedFactoryService))
            {
                yield return RegistrationBuilder.ForDelegate(typeof(Func<>).MakeGenericType(elementType), (c, p) =>
                                                {
                                                    // /!\ disposal of this object is not managed
                                                    Object fixedFactory = c.ResolveComponent(registration, p);
                                                    return getInstanceMethod.CreateDelegate(typeof(Func<>)
                                                                            .MakeGenericType(elementType), fixedFactory);
                                                })
                                                .As(service)
                                                .Targeting(registration)
                                                .CreateRegistration();
            }
        }
    }
```

2. use a *module* and browse the dependency graph. Quite difficult and you will have to understand perfectly how works *Autofac*.

I won't recommend doing that because all solution could be quite difficult and *Autofac* was not designed to works like this.

Comment: I suppose my usage of Autofac may be special since the container is never updated. In my example, if `AFactory` depends on `Func<B>` instead of `B` it would behave more like the automatic factories, so I made that edit to the question. The behavior remains the same with the exception being thrown when resolving `AFactory`. It sounds like creating a custom RegistrationSource may be the way to go. I've given some thought to #2 that you mentioned, but it seems like it would have pitfalls such as what to do with delegates and constructors that are never resolved by the application.

Comment: I edited my answer to provide a `FixedFactoryRegistrationSource` implementation for #1

Comment: Thanks, this gives me something to go on!